# ¿Por qué la función printf imprime basura?

Tags: c

El problema es que cuando ingreso solo 1 o 2 vocales al final de la cadena imprime basura. ¿Esto a que se debe?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    int cont=0, cont2=0, largo;
    char frase[50], aux[50];

    printf("Ingrese una frase:");
    gets(frase);

    largo = strlen(frase);

    for(int i=0; i<largo; i++){
            if(frase[i] == 97 || frase[i] == 101 || frase[i] == 105 || frase[i] == 111 || frase[i] == 117){
                aux[cont2++] = frase[i];

            }
            else if(frase[i] != 32){
                cont++;
            }
    }

    if(cont2 > 0){
        printf("\nEstas son las vocales:\t");
        puts(aux);
        printf("\nVocales en MAYUSCULAS:\t%s ", strupr(aux));
    }
    else{
        printf("\nNo hay vocales");
    }

    printf("\nHay %i consonantes", cont);

    return 0;
}
```

**Esto es lo que imprime con 1 o 2 vocales:**

**Prueba 1:**

```c
Ingrese una frase: i

Estas son las vocales:  i§@

Vocales en MAYUSCULAS:  I§@

Hay 0 consonantes
```

**Prueba 2:**

```c
Ingrese una frase: ii

Estas son las vocales:  ii@

Vocales en MAYUSCULAS:  II@

Hay 0 consonantes
```

Con 3 deja de imprimir basura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema radica que el array `aux` no está terminando con el caracter nulo (este caracter indica el fin de la cadena) y justamente, la función `strupr` (y no solamente esta función, sino, también `printf`, `puts`, entre otras) necesita ese caracter para poder terminar de recorrer el array de caracteres de forma exitosa, de lo contrario, estarías [desbordando el búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer) (el resultado es [indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido)).

Por lo tanto, el código debe quedar así:

```c
int main()
{
    int cont=0, cont2=0, largo;
    char frase[50], aux[50];

    printf("Ingrese una frase:");
    gets(frase);
    largo = strlen(frase);

    for(int i=0; i<largo; i++)
    {
        if(frase[i] == 97 || frase[i] == 101 || frase[i] == 105 || frase[i] == 111 || frase[i] == 117)
            aux[cont2++] = frase[i];
        else if(frase[i] != 32)
            cont++;
    }
    aux[cont2] = '\0'; //Hay que asignar el caracter nulo..
    if(cont2 > 0)
    {
        printf("\nEstas son las vocales:\t");
        puts(aux);
        printf("\nVocales en MAYUSCULAS:\t%s ", strupr(aux));
    }
    else{
        printf("\nNo hay vocales");
    }

    printf("\nHay %i consonantes", cont);

    return 0;
}
```

Una **observación**: La función [gets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/) es insegura (puede provocar un desbordamiento de búfer). Recomiendo que la reemplaces por [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/).

**Nota:** La función `strupr` no forma parte de la biblioteca estándar de C, por lo tanto, no todos los compiladores lo admiten. Si en algún momento tienes problemas con esta función, [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328095/14043783) hay un ejemplo de como la debes implementar.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: @Melibizu De nada! No olvides de [aceptar la respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas#:~:text=Se%20puede%20seleccionar%20cualquier%20respuesta,se%20puede%20aceptar%20una%20respuesta.) que resolvió tu problema.